# How do I fire downstream onEventTime() method when using BroadcastState pattern?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using a pipeline as follows:

```
inputStream.keyBy(<keyMapper>).
connect(configurationBroadcastStream).
process(new KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction<...>() {
     processBroadcastElement(...){...}
     processElement(...){...}
     }).
keyBy(<keyMapper>). // have to key output of process() again
window(DynamicEventTimeSessionWindow.withDynamicGap(...)).
trigger(new CustomTrigger()).
process(new CustomProcessWindowFn())
```

In the `CustomTrigger()`, I am registering an `eventTimeTimer()` that will fire to indicate the end of my window. The problem is that the `onEventTime()` method is **never** invoked, even when:

- I have ensured `env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);`
- Using an `ascendingTimestampExtractor()`, I have sent an event that has definitely pushed the watermark sufficiently far enough that the `eventTimeTimer()` should fire.

What am I missing? Does it have something to do with missing watermarks and the `onTimer()` method of the `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction`? I suspect so because of David Anderson's comment in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306916/using-broadcast-state-to-force-window-closure-using-fake-messages)
answer:

> add special fake watermarks for the non-broadcast stream (set to
>   Watermark.MAX_WATERMARK)

and the fact that I have not implemented a method named on**Timer**. However, if this indeed is the case, I don't understand how that would be relevant to a downstream Trigger. Thanks.

Edit: a full example of this scenario is [here](https://gist.github.com/manasIU/1777c9c99e195a409441815559094b49).

Comment: To elaborate more, the custom trigger is attempting to implement the functionality described in Till's example[1] while using the broadcastState pattern. [1] https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/ra6aa52be588bfec2ebe93bd157c3d939ab234038016abc9fc8694d14%40%3Cuser.flink.apache.org%3E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that the broadcast stream doesn't have watermarks. (But no, it doesn't matter if the `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction` has an onTimer method or not. Once you get the watermark flowing they will flow through to the window regardless.)

Whenever an operator has two or more inputs -- so in your case, when the `inputStream` and `configurationBroadcastStream` are connected -- the watermark at that operator will the minimum of the watermarks from its inputs. Since the broadcast stream doesn't have watermarks, this is holding back the watermarks provided by the `inputStream`.

I have an [example](https://github.com/ververica/flink-training-exercises/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ververica/flinktraining/solutions/datastream_java/broadcast/TaxiQuerySolution.java#L112) showing how you might handle this. Assuming that your broadcast stream doesn't need to have any timing information, you can implement a timestamp extractor and watermark assigner that effectively cedes control of watermarking to the other stream. Something like this:

```java
// Once the two streams are connected, the Watermark of the KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction operator
// will be the minimum of the Watermarks of the two connected streams. Our config stream has a default
// Watermark at Long.MIN_VALUE, and this will hold back the event time clock of the
// KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction, unless we do something about it.

public static class ConfigStreamAssigner implements AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<String> {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
        return Watermark.MAX_WATERMARK;
    }

    @Override
    public long extractTimestamp(String element, long previousElementTimestamp) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: That was indeed the problem, thanks. Do you think it's worth adding API-level checks to ensure that such a scenario does not happen when the operator pipeline is created? That is, if a user tries to connect an event time stream with a broadcast stream, Flink will force the user to implement getCurrentWatermark() for the broadcast stream.

Comment: Good point; I like this idea. But I think it should be addressed in a more general way. Wherever the pipeline uses event-time timers, all of the sources that can reach that operator need to have watermarks. Perhaps a check for this can be worked on after the ongoing reworking of watermarks being done with FLIP-27.